# How to deploy apk on multiple devices?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Before gradle 2.X.X every time I pressed "Run", a window pop-upped asking for target device, on gradle 2.x.x whatever I do, apk is deployed to the last used device/emulator.

P.S I dont check "use same device for future launches.
P.S.S at this moment I can get that window only if I attach new device to my pc, press run and then detach mock device.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using new "Instant run" feature? Is there a yellow lightning sign near the green run button?

Comment: @Orlangure instant run is disabled in my projects